# c# Post data cookies not working

Tags: c#, cookies, post

Alright, so I've got a function I wrote that should allow me to post data with cookies. The problem is is I'm testing it out on an Amazon login page, and it keeps responding saying I need cookies enabled. Here's the code

```
public string DoPost(String url, PostData data, CookieContainer cookies)
{
    HttpWebRequest objWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    objWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    objWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    objWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
    if(data != null)
    {
        String post = data.ToString();
        objWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        objWebRequest.ContentLength = post.Length;
        objWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Post to the login form.
        using(StreamWriter swRequestWriter = new StreamWriter(objWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            swRequestWriter.Write(post);
        }
    }

    // Get the response.
    HttpWebResponse objWebResponse =
         (HttpWebResponse)objWebRequest.GetResponse();

    // Read the response
    using(StreamReader srResponseReader = new StreamReader(objWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string strResponseData = srResponseReader.ReadToEnd();
        return strResponseData;
    }
}
```

And I call it like this

```
String action = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/flex/sign-in/select.html";
String s = DoPost(action, null, Cookies);
```

Cookies is created in my class constructer like this

```
CookieContainer Cookies;

public Constructz0r()
{
    Cookies = new CookieContainer();
}
```

The thing is, I'm not even posting any post data, I'm just going to the page, and it's saying my cookies aren't enabled, though I feel I've done it write in DoPost.

I've even tried using this implementation of WebClient

```
    public class CookieWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private CookieContainer _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
            }
            return request;
        }
}
```

And calling it like this

```
        using(CookieWebClient ck = new CookieWebClient())
        {
            String s =  ck.DownloadString(action);
        }
```

And it still tells me the cookies aren't enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon have an [API](http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/17/) to access their services (SOAP). So instead of trying to do some scraping I would strongly recommend you using their API.

Comment: right but that has to do with cloud hosting, and what I'm developing has nothing to do with AWS.

Comment: @kelton52, they have SOAP web services: http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/17/ Sorry, I have posted the wrong link in my answer. Should be fixed now.

Comment: That seems like way more than I need, plus I'm not working with wpf. I'm not even trying to log on yet, I just need amazon to realize I'm using cookies.

Comment: If a web browser can do it, I shouldn't need a special api.

Comment: @kelton52, that's SOAP, should be working with anything you could imagine, including WPF. And, yes of course, if a browser can do it, you can also. It's just that you shouldn't forget that in HTML5 there are things like local storage (totally unsupported by the .NET API), so if Amazon is checking for example your UserAgent and sees Mozilla or something it might think, well, that's Mozilla, let's test whether it supports local storage and of course it doesn't => you get an error. That's of course not documented. All I can do is wish you good luck in your endevour...

Comment: ... and of course if you want to make this work you could try their API. You cannot expect anything good from undocumented things.

Comment: The example uses soap. Another problem with the api, is I need to log on as multiple different users, and the api doesn't seem to have any specific login function. You would need a specific api key for each user, and that won't work.

Comment: @kelton52, you could always contact them and explain your scenarios and ask for support. After all you are using their product, aren't you? Don't expect anyone here helping you with such things.

Comment: Why wouldn't anyone here help? That is kind of the point of this site, isn't it?

Comment: @kelton52, I already provided an answer trying to help you, the way in my opinion would be best to solve your problem so that other people having the same problem as you and looking for an answer could do this. If you don't agree my answer feel totally free to downvote it or wait for a *better* (in your opinion) answer. I will not change or delete it as that's what I think is the correct way to do in this situation.

Comment: I never asked you to delete it, but it certainly doesn't solve the question that I asked.

Comment: @Kelton52 you won't get much help because the problem is not you code more the unsupported nature of what you are doing, your question assumes that this SHOULD work but that is not the case, it may it may not amazon can chose any method they wish to decide to display that error and even if you got  it to work it might fail again at any time whereas an api has documented behaviour and is supported and maintained.

Comment: Makes sense, but then that should have been your answer. Anyways, I found the answer.